# Android .Decrypt Existing Sqlite runntime in android

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

I need a local database for my application.I created one and i encrypted it.(I know the password).Now i want to load this db to my original application.I want to decrypte it before copy. I had a copy code like this this is working for unencrpyted db. How can I translate this for my encrypted db.Thanks

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}
```

Comment: Copy it to your app's data directory first, then run the decryption routine and then copy the decrypted file to your original database location

Comment: Thank for your comment
But how run decryption

Comment: well that depends on how you encrypted the file...

Comment: Just by DB Browser for SQLite...

Comment: Assuming that you used the [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/)  extensions for SQLite, I recommend you use the [Android Library](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) provided by the project and follow the steps [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/)

Comment: sorry I dont use SQLChiper ... how can i use it..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking on the [wiki](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Encrypted-Databases) on DB Browser for SQLite repo, DB Browser uses [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/) as a default encryption extension, so I assume that you have used the default SQLCipher extension. This means that to use that encrypted DB file on Android, you need to use SQLCipher's [Android Port](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/).

More examples and documentation can be found in their [Android Repo](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) and [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/).

### Update:

This update explains a sample setup for using `SQLiteCipher`.

1. Add SQLCipher dependency in your application's build.gradle file:
   `compile net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.7@aar`
2. Initialize SQLCipher's native library before performing any db ops by calling:
   `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(context)`
3. (*optional*, recommended) Create an implementation of: 
   `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper` or, better yet, make your existing `SQLiteOpenHelper` extend from this class
4. Then whenever you request a database (`getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`), supply your encryption password with it, e.g.,
   `SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase(_PASSWORD_)`

See more details on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/riyaz-ali/07c7bb60a9a1e98ba766099777676edf).

Also, in your case you need to copy the encrypted database from the raw assets folder to the path returned by calling [Context.getDatabasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) for the first time your app is run.

Hope this explains the things to you,
Regards

Comment: I dont Khow How appreciate you ... today I spend lots of time in order to Implementation of SQLCipher ... but I couldnt do that ... i will be more thankful if show me simple AndroidStudio Project that use existing encrypted Sqlite database...

Comment: Hooray It finally done ... Thanks for mr.riyaz-ali ... you helped me alot ... I hope can once a day afford compensate

Comment: @MostafaDaneshfar Hehe ;P :) Happy to help P.S. Please mark the answer as accepted of it solved your problem so others can refer it in future